# Loading 35000 rows from DB using linq make WPF page loading slow

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql

**Scenario:**

I have a TelerikAutoComplete control in one of my WPF page and the item source is a property which is filled from 35000 rows from a table in DB.

**Issue :**

It takes longer to retrieve the data which is hampering the load of the page.

**Resolution Tried:**
[EDITED]
Cause of issue was different which has been defined in answer below.

Let me know in case you need more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1)Why are you loading 35000 rows, 2)Does loading takes much time or populating the grid takes? 3) If latter takes much time, Why do you load 35000 rows in grid? Is the user going to view all? Have you ever heard of paging?

Comment: Sriram Sakthivel@ This is not the grid , it a auto complete on a text box. I am sorry but havent heard of paging in Auto Complete.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked. Ok have you found which part it takes time? Loading from DB or populating auto complete ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel If it is autocomplete then maybe not handle it by loading it all, but ask the database for the matches. THat is "not small data 101".

Comment: No sure who and why down voted this post/question, can I get the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this delay was the database. We had this data coming from view which was taking whole lot of time. Changed this view into table and it made processing really quick..Sorry for late answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about: Do not load 35000 rows. That is not a sane UI if it needs all pages loaded. So, use virtualization.

> I tried using the background worker, since that also derived by
>   dispatcher thread it still hold the page until the data is filled up
>   in the property.

Ah, no. Back to documentation becasue quite obviously you are not using it correctly.

Comment: TomTom@you mean bg worker is not used properly? if it is so, let me check again.tx

Comment: TomTom@ Actually that was one of the project level implementation which was blocking the page until the whole data is loaded...my bad .